Azure Datafactory selfhodhosted integration runtime: Bad Remote Access configurations
I am installing selfhosted integration runtime software on a Windows VM.
All of the existing nodes of the datafactory are removed prior to the registration..
For registration, I run this command:
dmgcmd.exe -Key $authKey
and that gives me this:
Remote Access should be enabled on this node. To enable it, you can run 'dmgcmd.exe -EnableRemoteAccess "<port>" ["<thumbprint>"]'.
Why would it say that?
Since this is a single-node config, I expected the registration to complete without remote access

On another environment, I got this:
Registration of new node is forbidden when Remote Access is disabled on another node. To enable it, you can login the machine where the other node is installed and run 'dmgcmd.exe -EnableRemoteAccess "<port>" ["<thumbprint>"]'.
Same situation here: alle nodes are removed before registration and the message appears when registering a new (first) IR ..


On another environment, I got this: Registration of new node is forbidden when Remote Access is disabled on another node. To enable it, you can login the machine where the other node is installed and run 'dmgcmd.exe -EnableRemoteAccess "<port>" ["<thumbprint>"]'. Same situation here: alle nodes are removed before registration and the message appears when registering a new (first) IR

According to the MS document
You don't need to create a new self-hosted integration runtime to associate each node. You can install the self-hosted integration runtime on another machine and register it by using the same authentication key. Before you add another node for high availability and scalability, ensure that the Remote access to intranet option is enabled on the first node. That may be the reason to get below error:

Remote Access should be enabled on this node. To enable it, you can run 'dmgcmd.exe -EnableRemoteAccess "" [""]'

To resolve enable remote access in the VM using below PowerShell command:
 dmgcmd.exe -EnableRemoteAccess "<port>" ["<thumbprint>"]

For more information you can refer to the MS document.
